# creating a dataframe and based on 2 dataframe sets that have different lengths

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe sets , I want to create a third one. I am trying to to write a code that to do the following :
if A_pd["from"] and A_pd["To"]  is within the range of B_pd["from"]and B_pd["To"] then add to the C_pd dateframe  A_pd["from"] and A_pd["To"] and B_pd["Value"].

if the  A_pd["from"] is  within the range of B_pd["from"]and B_pd["To"] and A_pd["To"] within the range of B_pd["from"]and B_pd["To"] of teh next row , then i want to split the range A_pd["from"] and A_pd["To"] to 2 ranges (A_pd["from"] and B_pd["To"]) and ( B_pd["To"] and A_pd["To"] ) and the corresponded B_pd["Value"].

I created the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

A_pd = {'from':[0,20,80,180,250],
        'To':[20, 50,120,210,300]}

A_pd=pd.DataFrame(A_pd)

B_pd = {'from':[0,20,100,200],
    'To':[20, 100,200,300],
    'Value':[20, 17,15,12]}
B_pd=pd.DataFrame(B_pd)

for i in range(len(A_pd)):
    numberOfIntrupt=0 
    for j in range(len(B_pd)): 
        if A_pd["from"].values[i] >= B_pd["from"].values[j] and A_pd["from"].values[i] >  B_pd["To"].values[j]:
            numberOfIntrupt+=1
cols = ['C_from', 'C_To', 'C_value']
C_dp=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=range(len(A_pd)+numberOfIntrupt))           

for i in range(len(A_pd)):
    for j in range(len(B_pd)): 
        a=A_pd ["from"].values[i]
        b=A_pd["To"].values[i]
        c_eval=B_pd["Value"].values[j]
        range_s=B_pd["from"].values[j]
        range_f=B_pd["To"].values[j]
        if a >= range_s and a <=  range_f and b >= range_s and b <=  range_f :
            C_dp['C_from'].loc[i]=a
            C_dp['C_To'].loc[i]=b
            C_dp['C_value'].loc[i]=c_eval
       
        elif a >= range_s and b > range_f:
            C_dp['C_from'].loc[i]=a
            C_dp['C_To'].loc[i]=range_f
            C_dp['C_value'].loc[i]=c_eval
            C_dp['C_from'].loc[i+1]=range_f
            C_dp['C_To'].loc[i+1]=b
            C_dp['C_value'].loc[i+1]=B_pd["Value"].values[j+1]
        

print(C_dp)
```

The current result is C_dp:

```
C_from C_To C_value
0      0   20      20
1     20   50      17
2     80  100      17
3    180  200      15
4    250  300      12
5    200  300      12
6    NaN  NaN     NaN
7    NaN  NaN     NaN
```

the expected should be :

```
C_from C_To C_value
0      0   20      20
1     20   50      17
2     80  100      17
3    100  120      15
4    180  200      15
5    200  210      12
6    250  300     12
```

Thank you a lot for the support

Comment: Your question is not clear a bit can you explain the question a bit.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will explain it as example :

lets say the raw in A_pd is 0,10 ,  this range of values is within the first raw in B_pd 0,20,20 ,  so the first raw in C_pd will be 0,10, 20 ... if the raw in A_pd is 80,120, then the value 80 will be more than B_pd.['from'].value[1] but the 120 is more than B_pd.['to'].value[1], therefore the value 80-120 should be divided to 80-100 and 100-120 , because they are under different categories  B_pd.['value']

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this without loops, but this will help your logic flow.

```py
import pandas as pd

A_pd = {'from':[0,  20,  80, 180, 250],
          'To':[20, 50, 120, 210, 300]}

A_pd=pd.DataFrame(A_pd)

B_pd = {'from':[0,  20, 100, 200],
          'To':[20, 100,200, 300],
       'Value':[20, 17,  15,  12]}
B_pd=pd.DataFrame(B_pd)


cols = ['C_from', 'C_To', 'C_value']
C_dp=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
spillover = False
for i in range(len(A_pd)):
    for j in range(len(B_pd)):
        a_from = A_pd["from"].values[i]
        a_to = A_pd["To"].values[i]
        b_from = B_pd["from"].values[j]
        b_to = B_pd["To"].values[j]
        b_value = B_pd['Value'].values[j]

        if (a_from >= b_to):
            # a_from outside b range
            continue    # next b
        
        elif (a_from >= b_from):
            # a_from within b range
            if a_to <= b_to:
                C_dp = C_dp.append({"C_from": a_from, "C_To": a_to, "C_value": b_value}, ignore_index=True)
                break   # next a
            else:
                C_dp = C_dp.append({"C_from": a_from, "C_To": b_to, "C_value": b_value}, ignore_index=True)
                if j < len(B_pd):
                    spillover = True
                    continue
        
        if spillover:
            if a_to <= b_to:
                C_dp = C_dp.append({"C_from": b_from, "C_To": a_to, "C_value": b_value}, ignore_index=True)
                spillover = False
                break
            else:
                C_dp = C_dp.append({"C_from": b_from, "C_To": b_to, "C_value": b_value}, ignore_index=True)
                spillover = True
                continue

print(C_dp)
```

Output

```py
  C_from C_To C_value
0      0   20      20
1     20   50      17
2     80  100      17
3    100  120      15
4    180  200      15
5    200  210      12
6    250  300      12
```

Comment: Thank you @Davis